# How to make a button press once and wait until the second button is pressed and viceversa

Tags: java, android

Hello this is my code in android studio.

```
public class GroupDesign extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Spectrum Inc";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_design);

        //button do suf

                Button lock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lockit);
                //set what happens when pressed
                lock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "This is a secure message!");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Door Locked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                    }
                });
                  Button unlock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.unlockit);
                //set what happens when pressed
                unlock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "This is a secure message!");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Door Unlocked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });


        }
    }
```

Comment: Use boolean flags and update those flags as and when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: You basically want only one button to be available at any instant. Either Lock or unlock and not both. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean flag. Update the button's enabled status or even visibility if you want to hide the button.

```
boolean locked = false;
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_design);
    Button lock, unlock;
    lock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lockit); //set what happens when pressed 
    lock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i(TAG, "This is a secure message!");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Door Locked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
            locked = true;
            unlock.setEnabled(true);
            lock.setEnabled(false); 
            }
    }); 
    unlock = (Button)     findViewById(R.id.unlockit); //set what happens when pressed 
    unlock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i(TAG, "This is a secure message!"); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Door Unlocked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show(); 
            locked = false;
            lock.setEnabled(true);
            unlock.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}
}
```

if you want to hide the button instead of disabling, you can replace `setEnabled(false)` with `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Or if you are not doing much, you can have just a single button and change the label text instead.

Comment: Hello thanks for the replies I ended up hiding the buttons instead. Thanks